# PyTorch: Convolving a single channel image using torch.nn.Conv2d

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution, tensor

I am trying to use a convolution layer to convolve a grayscale (single layer) image (stored as a numpy array). Here is the code:

```
conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 1, out_channels = 1, kernel_size = 33)
tensor1 = torch.from_numpy(img_gray)
out_2d_np = conv1(tensor1)

out_2d_np = np.asarray(out_2d_np)
```

I want my kernel to be 33x33 and the number of output layers should be equal to the number of input layers, which is 1 as the image's RGB channels are summed. When`out_2d_np = conv1(tensor1)` is run it yields the following runtime error:

> RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 1 1 33 33, but got 2-dimensional input of size [246, 248] instead

Any idea on how I can solve this? I specifically want to use the `torch.nn.Conv2d()` class/function.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pytorch's `Conv2d` expects its 2D inputs to actually have **4** dimensions: mini-batch dim, channel dim, and the two spatial dimensions.
Your input tensor has only two spatial dimensions and it lacks the mini-batch and channel dimensions. In your case these two dimensions are actually singelton dimensions (dimensions with size=1).

try:

```
conv1(tensor1[None, None, ...])
```