# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3) on torchvision

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, streamlit, torchvision

Trying to classify images using custom Pytorch model on Streamlit.

Now before prediction, the served image is first converted with torchvision, however, the following error pops up when I try to predict:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
>
> Traceback: File
>
> "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu2.5\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py",
> line 557, in _run_script
> exec(code, module.**dict**) File "app_v2.py", line 48, in 
> predict(image, model) File "app_v2.py", line 25, in predict
> pred = model(x) File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu2.5\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 889, in _call_impl
> result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs) File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu2.5\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py",
> line 27, in decorate_context
> return func(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\PC/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\common.py",
> line 573, in forward
> return self.model(imgs.to(p.device).type_as(p), augment, profile)  # inference File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu2.5\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 889, in _call_impl
> result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\PC/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\common.py",
> line 443, in forward
> b, ch, h, w = im.shape  # batch, channel, height, width

code basically looks like:

```
## Serve Image
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader('Upload image...', type=['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])

if uploaded_file is not None:
    ## convert
    image = Image.open(uploaded_file).convert('L')
    predict(image, model)
```

```
def predict(image, model):
    ## convert
    x = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()(image)
    pred = model(x)
    pred = pred.detach().numpy()
```

Would appreciate the assistance.
Thanks

Comment: Do the variable names in problem line suggest sknething?  ` b, ch, h, w` - batch, channel, height, width?  Does your data `image` have those 4 dimensions?

Comment: Yes, i think it does - worked with @Shia response and the Runtime error suggests this. -> " weight of size [32, 3, 6, 6]"

Answer (score 0):

Your input image `x` has only three dimensions: channels (RGB), height and width.
PyTorch expects input images to have [four dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60422461/1714410): batch, channels, height and width.

You need to add a singleton "batch" dimension:

```py
pred = model(x[None, ...])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Shai.

Tried this and a new error:
> RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 6, 6], expected input[1, 1, 480, 480] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead

Popped Up, please assist.

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I solved this problem, for anyone else, this was ultimately an Image Classification challenge using Pytorch's custom model on streamlit. So rigged the whole thing.

The following works.

```
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import torch
import io

## LOAD MODEL
run_model_path = './model_file.pt'
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path=run_model_path)
model.eval()

## Collect
img_file_buffer = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Upload an Image", type=["jpg", "jpeg", "png"])
if img_file_buffer is not None:
    image = np.array(Image.open(img_file_buffer))
    ## Predict Image
    result = model(image)
    ## Convert Image format
    output = io.BytesIO()
    out_image = np.squeeze(result.render()) ## to numpy array
    o_img = Image.fromarray(out_image) ## to PIL
    o_img.save(output, format='JPEG')
    result_img = output.getvalue() ## Back to JPEG
    ## Show Result
    st.image(result_img)
```

So train (hard stuff) save in the same directory you run your app.

Phew.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an RGB image (dimension 3), which is missing the dimension for the batch size, hence an expected dimension 4. To **prepend** this dimension to your image, use the following.

With NumPy:

```py
import numpy as np

image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
```

With PyTorch:

```py
import torch

image = torch.unsqueeze(image, dim=0)
```

Alternatively:

```py
image = image[None, :]
```

Or, solely because you **preprend** this dimension, you can omit the colon `:`:

```py
image = image[None]
```